# How to install Google Cloud SDK on Travis?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, travis-ci

I have tried to install Google Cloud SDK on Travis with the following `.travis.yml`

```
sudo: required

language: go

- curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash;
```

My attempt is inspired by this guide from Google: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-with-travis-ci

Unfortunately, I get this output on Travis:

```
$ curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash;
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   421    0   421    0     0  17820      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 60142
Downloading Google Cloud SDK install script: https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash
######################################################################## 100.0%
Running install script from: /tmp/tmp.uz8jP70e56/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash
which curl
curl -# -f https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
Installation directory (this will create a google-cloud-sdk subdirectory) (/home/travis):
```

Travis waits for 10 minutes and then terminates the build. It seems like it is waiting for an installation directory.

How do I install Google Cloud SDK on Travis?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are running into this issue because there is no interaction possible on Travis CI. Hence, the installation script is blocked waiting for input and Travis CI kills the build after 10 minutes.

The trick is to disable the prompts when installing the Google Cloud SDK. This can be done by setting the `CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS` environment variable to `1`.

Here's a sample recipe to put in your .travis.yml file (including caching it for faster subsequent builds):

```
cache:
  directories:
    - "$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/"
script:
  - gcloud version || true
  - if [ ! -d "$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin" ]; then rm -rf $HOME/google-cloud-sdk; export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1; curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash; fi
  # Add gcloud to $PATH
  - source /home/travis/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
  - gcloud version
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As of today this setup fails :-(

Comment: @BobvanLuijt It works for me: https://travis-ci.org/cotsog/travis_ci_prod_regular/builds/393693001. Could you send an e-mail to support [at] travis-ci [dot] com so we can have a look? Thanks!